# Algoritmo de controle de temperatura

Tags: algoritmo

Eu sou um aluno de engenharia da computação e estou trabalhando em um Termociclador PCR.

Eu preciso ter uma certa temperatura precisa para poder realizar todos as etapas do processo, e eu estou tendo alguns problemas com isso. Eu e minha equipe estamos utilizando simples ligar-desligar para controlar a temperatura, funciona, mas temos uma média de 1°c de variação na temperatura e isso não é muito bom para um PCR, a grande pergunta é, algum de vocês teria conhecimento de um algoritmo para controle de temperatura que seja eficiente e me de a menor variação de temperatura possível?

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é está em EN no SOPT.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. O idioma oficial usado aqui é o Português, você
poderia traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no 
[StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Please translate this question to Portuguese or use the standard version of the SO.

Comment: Precisa ser mais especifico dizendo qual a linguagem, mostrando o código que possui e quais valores saem e quais deveriam sair.

Answer (score 2):

Desligando e ligando você vai ter além de uma variação de 1ºc, vc também vai ter um desgaste físico do relee (imagino eu que você esteja usando ele), dependendo do microcontrolador e do nível de programação que estiverem fazendo (se esta trabalhando direto no micro ou por uma API externa) aconselho o uso do [PWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation). Se você postar mais informações sobre o projeto eu posso dar mais sugestões. Acredito que hoje, todos os microcontroladores tem pelo menos 3 pinos com saídas PWM, nessas saídas você pode modular o pulso (ou seja, não ter 5v contínuos ou 3.3 contínuos) assim dando mais precisão a temperatura